# Why does the first function call bind to the first function?

Tags: c++, function, templates, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

Why does the first function call (`cm(car);`) bind to the first function?

I understand that second call is bound to second function because it's non-template, despite both being perfect matches.

If the first function is defined as non-template with fixed array length, as:

```
    void cm(const char (&h)[8]) {cout << "const char (&)[8]" << endl;}
```

than again it gets selected over the second one (the second call will be ambiguous that way).

Code:

```
template<size_t N> void cm(const char (&h)[N]) 
    {std::cout << " const (&)[N] " << endl;}

void cm(const char * h)
    {cout << " const char * " << endl;}

int main()
{
    char car[] = "errqweq";
    const char ccar[] = "errqweq";
    cm(car);
    cm(ccar);
}
```

Output:

```
 const (&)[N]
 const char *
```

Answer (score 4):

The first call chooses the function template specialization - because it's a better match.
Let us label both overloads:

```
template<size_t N> void cm(const char (&h)[N])  // (1) - the specialization
    {std::cout << " const (&)[N] " << endl;}

void cm(const char * h)                         // (2)
    {cout << " const char * " << endl;}
```

For (1), `car` binds to a reference. That is an identity conversion<sup>1</sup>.
For (2), after the array-to-pointer conversion of `car`, which yields `char*`<sup>2</sup>, a qualification conversion has to be done so `char*` becomes 
`char const*`. That is now invoking this:

> Standard conversion sequence `S1` is a better conversion sequence than
>   standard conversion sequence `S2` if
>
> - `S1` is a proper subsequence of `S2` (comparing the conversion sequences in the canonical form defined by 13.3.3.1.1, **excluding any
>     Lvalue Transformation; the identity conversion sequence is
>     considered to be a subsequence of any non-identity conversion
>     sequence**) or, if not that,
> - […]

An array-to-pointer conversion is an Lvalue Transformation, so it isn't considered here - just as in the second example. The qualification conversion has an own category though: *Qualification Adjustment*. Therefore the conversion to the parameter of (1) is a subsequence of the conversion to the parameter of (2): The first is an identity conversion and the second a qualification conversion, and according to the paragraph above an identity conversion is a subsequence of any non-identity conversion. So (1) is chosen.

As you already mentioned yourself, in the second case the conversions are equally good; The quote above does not work since the conversion to (2)s parameter is not a subsequence of the conversion to the parameter of (1). Hence, [over.match.best]/1 applies.

> Given these definitions, a viable function `F1` is defined to be a
>   better function than another viable function `F2` if for all arguments
>   i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and then
>
> - for some argument j, ICSj(F1) is a better conversion sequence than ICSj(F2), or, if not that,
> - the context is an initialization by user-defined conversion […], or, if not that,
> - **`F1` is a non-template function and `F2` is a function template specialization**,

So (2) one is chosen. If the function template wasn't a template but a function with parameter 
`char const (&)[8]` the call would be ambiguous [as Clang correctly says](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bf0cdd049214491).

---

<sup>1</sup>  [over.ics.ref]/1:

> **When a parameter of reference type binds directly (8.5.3) to an
>   argument expression, the implicit conversion sequence is the identity
>   conversion**, unless the argument expression has a type that is a
>   derived class of the parameter type, in which case the implicit
>   conversion sequence is a derived-to-base Conversion (13.3.3.1).

[dcl.init.ref]/5 (which is in 8.5.3):

> In all cases except the last (i.e., creating and initializing a
>   temporary from the initializer expression), the reference is said to
>   *bind directly* to the initializer expression.

<sup>2</sup> [conv.array]:

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of `N T`” or “array of unknown
>   bound of `T`” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to `T`”.
>   The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.

`T` can be cv-qualified, and so would the type of the pointee be. Here `T` is just `char`, so the pointer is of type pointer to `char` => `char*`.

Comment: "binds directly" doesn't seem to be defined by 8.5.3. Are you saying that binding a non-const array to a const reference counts as "binds directly" ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Since it seems this might confuse more people I added a footnote. :) (It is defined, see my footnote)

Comment: AH I overlooked that. So it means any reference binding that doesn't involve a temporary.

Answer (score 2):

Because the string "errqweq" directly written in the code is read only because it is, at run time, in a part of memory "protected" as it is managed as a constant.

Pointing at it using a `const char* ccar;` or a `const char ccar[];` is correct. You are pointing to the memory holding the original "errqweq" with the const specifier: the compiler ensure that the string will be not modified.

But look at: `char car[] = "errqweq";`

In order to provide you a modificable buffer (as you are requesting without the const modifier) the compiler create an array of 8 elements (7 chars + \0) on the stack copying in it (i.e: intializing it) the string "errqweq".

So the first call is using a `char buffer[8]` arguments that is safely converted to a `const char buffer[8]`. Obviously the fixed size of the array give a best match with the template instead of the more "weak" bind with the function that requires "just" a constant pointer.

Comment: Huh, I never knew that `const char[]` would do that with a string literal, I thought it would behave like `char[]` in this case.

Comment: The argumentation in the last paragraph of your answer is incorrect, isn't it?